# Generate and attach a file in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

How do I generate a (text only) file in Drupal 7, and attach it to a particular node automatically.

Is there a way to do this with a module, or should I use code to do it in some way (this seems tricky).

Answer (score 1):

First create a file using the drupal [file_save_data](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_data/7)

```
$data = 'Your text data';     // Text data to be saved to file.
$filename = 'filename.txt';   // Filename
$file = file_save_data($data,'public://' .$filename);
```

Now $file will contain the file object that we can attach to the node. Let say you have already created and attached a file field to node type. Lets call it 'field_custom_file'

Then load the node you want to attach then cast the file object to array and attach it to the field.

```
$node = node_load($nid);  // $nid is the id of the node where you want to attach the file.
$node->field_custom_file[LANGUAGE_NONE][] = (array)$file;
node_save($node);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = (object) array(
    'uid' => 1,
    'uri' => $filepath,
    'filemime' => file_get_mimetype($filepath),
    'status' => 1,
    'display' => 1,
);
$file = file_copy($file, 'public://');
$node->field_file['und'][0] = $file;
```